# Which route is better for a Neutral-risk person?

Tags: decision-theory, utility, lotteries

There are two routes, 1 and 2.

It is known that route 1 takes 60 minutes and route 2 takes 41 minutes.

If there is problems in the traffic:

Route 1 will increase to 70 minutes;

Route 2 will increase for 90 minutes.

The probability of traffic problems for:

Route 1 is 0.2;

Route 2 is 0.92.

How can I know which route is better for a risk neutral person?

Calculations:

Route 1:

$0.2*(70)+0.8*(60)=62$

Route 2:

$0.92*(90)+0.08*(41)=86.08$

How can I obtain the required information ( which route is a better route for a neutral risk person) without having the utility function?

Can anyone give me an hint?

Thanks

Comment: Your utility function is the expected duration of the trip.  There will be an expected duration for route 1, and for route 2.  Calculate these and choose the fastest (on average) route.

Comment: As I read it, your numbers are transposed.  I think you should have $(0.8)(60)+ (0.2)(70)$ and $(0.08)(41) + (0.92)(90)$

Comment: You are right, I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what's being described here, you have already solved the problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_neutral

Risk-neutral people don't worry about the uncertainty involved, they just maximize expected utility. Based on your route calculations, route 1 is generally faster.

Comment: So, because route 2 is faster, it should be the best option for a neutral risk person?

Comment: I think the answer is backwards? The computations show that route 1 has a lower expected time, so it is faster *on average*, i.e. in expected value, and a risk-neutral person only cares about the average.  We have to be clear about this: just saying that one route "is faster" is ambiguous.

Comment: yes makes sense, the fastest route is route 1 as it takes less time on average, but I do not understand why a risk neutral person would chose route 1 (fastest route). Can anyone clarify? thanks

Comment: The risk neutral person chooses the best expected value.  They don't have any extra constraints.  An example of a risk-averse person would be someone who would get in trouble if they weren't there in 80 minutes. That person would always choose route 1 because they can't afford to be late.  An example of a risk-seeking person would be someone who's hoping to get stuck in traffic so they have an excuse to be late.  They will choose route 2 for the better chance of traffic.  A risk-neutral person might be someone driving the route 1000's of times.  They want overall efficiency.

Comment: The best expected value in this case is the fastest route that is route 1 as it takes less time. Therefore a risk neutral person will chose route 1. Is this correct? thank you

Comment: Yes.  (Answer edited for corrected calculations)