# Meaning of term "risk neutral" (according to Williams' "Introduction to the Mathematics of Finance")

Tags: soft-question, terminology, finance

On page 12 in R.J. Williams' *Introduction to the Mathematics of Finance*, the author states that under the risk neutral measure, the discounted underlying stock price is a martingale.

He then follows with an explanation why this measure is called "risk neutral", which I cannot follow. More specifically, he uses an analogy to risk neutral persons, but I do not understand what the risk neutrality of the described "risk neutral person" has to do with the properties of the so called "risk neutral measure":

> A person is said to be "risk averse" if the person prefers the
>   expected value of a payoff to the random payoff itself. A person is
>   said to be "risk preferring" if the person prefers the random payoff
>   to the expected value of the payoff. A person is "risk neutral" if the
>   person is neither risk averse nor risk preferring; in other words the
>   person is indifferent, having no preference for the expected payoff
>   versos the random payoff. The probability $p*$ [the setup is a
>   discrete time single phase binomial model, where $p$ is the true
>   up-probability of the underlying] is called a *risk neutral
>   probability* because under $p^*$, a risk neutral investor would be
>   indifferent to the choice at time zero of investing in stock or bond,
>   since both investments have the same expected payoff at time $1$ under
>   $p^*$.

In my understanding, stock and bond having the same expected payoff is a prerequisite for the differences of the three described persona to even become appreciable, so I don't understand why the assumption that this prerequisite is satisfied would be connoted to a single one of these persona. In other words, the definition of "risk neutrality" seems to be a matter of expectations (since it entails a martingale property), whereas risk aversity or risk preference as described in the quote are a matter of variances and I don't see their connection. You can still be risk averse or risk preferring, even when the discounted stock is a martingale (i.e. you have a risk neutral measure).

Can anyone help me get a better understanding of the quote and/or the term "risk neutral"?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question.  You have a choice of two payouts:  one pays $X$ always.  One pays $X\pm c$ with equal probability.  A risk averse person prefers the first, a risk preferring person prefers the latter, a risk neutral person does not have a preference.

Comment: Possibly relevant:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544938/which-route-is-better-for-a-neutral-risk-person/2544961#2544961

Comment: @lulu I understand that part. What I don't understand is why the risk neutral person serves as eponym for the measure under which stock and bond have the same expectations

Comment: @lulu I changed the question a bit too make more clear that I am not asking  for clarification of what a "risk neutral person" is, but how the character quality of being "risk neutral" has to do with the mathematical finance property of a measure to be "risk neutral". In other words, I am asking how the properties of "risk neutral measures" deserve the adjective "risk neutral", I am NOT asking how the behavior of the described "risk neutral persona" deserves the adjective "risk neutral"

Comment: Ignore discounting for a moment. For a risk averse person, price needs to be lower than expected payoff. For a risk neutral person, the two are equal. Under the risk-neutral measure, value processes are martingales. Therefore, price is equal to expected payoff under this measure. That is where the name comes from.

Comment: @Calculon Does the following summary of my current understanding make sense to you? "If we have a market consisting of a bond with rate $r$ and a stock with rate $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma>0$, then $r>\mu$ would mean we live in a *risk averse* world, $r<\mu$ would mean we live in a *risk preferring* world, and $r=\mu$ means we live in a *risk neutral* world. In other words, the *risk neutral* in *risk neutral measure* means that one is considering the measure under which the market behaves as if its participants were *risk neutral persona*."

Comment: You could look at it that way. Indeed. in the real world $\mu >r$ typically holds and we "know" from social experiments that people are risk averse. When you switch to the risk neutral description of the stock price process $\mu = r$ holds (under the assumption of absence of arbitrage).